# "The method '>' was called on null." when trying to add index to Bottom Navigation Bar

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to add the currentIndex-Property.

I'm pretty sure I did it exactly like this in some older projects and don't get why it doesn't work.

```dart
int _currentIndex = 0;
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
  currentIndex: _currentIndex,
  onTap: (int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index; 
    });
  },
  items: [
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.bubble_chart),
      title: Text("Home")
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.timelapse),
      title: Text("Timeline")
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline),
      title: Text("Home")
    )
  ],
),
```

The error output is

```
I/flutter (11694): The method '>' was called on null.
I/flutter (11694): Receiver: null
I/flutter (11694): Tried calling: >(0)
```

Comment: The problem is not in that piece of code, I copied and pasted it here and it worked.

Comment: https://github.com/ccastroelo/sof2

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this exact issue as well today. I don't have an answer for what caused it, but I can describe the bizarre chain of events that led to its disappearance.

My code is nearly identical to yours. Instead of using _currentIndex, I used _selectedIndex as my variable name. If I switched:

```
currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
```

to

```
currentIndex: 0,
```

the error went away. (Yes, _selectedIndex was being initialized to 0)

Eventually I ended up trying "random" things to correct the issue. What ended up working for me was changing the variable name from _selectedIndex to selectedIndex. Yep, that's it. Then, even more bizarre, when I switched it back to _selectedIndex immediately afterwards, the error didn't come back.

I don't have a good enough understanding of the internals of the flutter SDK to hypothesize what was happening, so I won't. This worked for me and hopefully it works for others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, i encountered this issue too!

Finnally, i found that my `_currentIndex` is `null`,  just check it for your own!

In my case, `_currentIndex` is assigned by its constructor to specify the initial index, which I forgot to enter when I called it.